# Put picture into table cell with horizontall scrolling when overflow occurs

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, overflow

I have following html table fragment:

```
<td>
<div>

    <a class="fancy_image" href="/owner/createCompany/getOriginalImage/3" title=""><img class="image-lis-in-table-cell" src="/owner/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/3" alt=""></a>

    <a class="fancy_image" href="/owner/createCompany/getOriginalImage/1" title=""><img class="image-lis-in-table-cell" src="/owner/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/1" alt=""></a>

    <a class="fancy_image" href="/owner/createCompany/getOriginalImage/5" title=""><img class="image-lis-in-table-cell" src="/owner/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/5" alt=""></a>

    <a class="fancy_image" href="/owner/createCompany/getOriginalImage/2" title=""><img class="image-lis-in-table-cell" src="/owner/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/2" alt=""></a>

    <a class="fancy_image" href="/owner/createCompany/getOriginalImage/4" title=""><img class="image-lis-in-table-cell" src="/owner/createCompany/getMediumThumbnail/4" alt=""></a>

</div>
</td>
```

it looks like this:

[image]

When I have more than 2 pictures in table cell `tr` heigh changes. It looks ugly. I want that pictures was rendered only within one line and if there are too many pictures I want to see scroll.

Can provide styles for my desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
.image-lis-in-table-cell {
       margin: auto;
       white-space: nowrap;
       width: 100%;
       overflow:auto; }
```

if you needed more then you can use any of 
      `overflow-x:scroll` or `overflow-y:scroll`;

Comment: Now it looks like this:http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/150914/c0ad8a9ebb.jpg